# Normal vector to a cube for divergence theorem

Tags: calculus

Typically I have been doing examples in vector calculus where the unit normal has been given by the clockwise or anticlockwise rotation using the right hand rule, however I have a cube that is  0<x,y,z<3 and I don’t know the direction of the normal vector could someone offer some help finding the unit vector generally and what steps I have to take when I don’t have rotation.

Okay so what I think is that the normal vector will go outwards from the top of the cube like a normal vector to a plane is that right?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

For closed surfaces, like the surface of your cube, the unit normal vector is typically defined as pointing toward the outside. If you are taking a surface integral over the surface of the cube, you should split that integral into 6 integrals over the individual faces of the cube and add them up at the end. For each of those 6 face integrals, the unit normal vector will be constant. For example, for the bottom face of the cube, assuming the $z$-axis is the vertical axis, the unit normal vector will be $(0, 0, -1)$. Hope it helps!

Comment: can I choose which way it points outside of the cube so can I choose the positive or negative z direction? 

And for a cylinder the unit normal points horizontally why is this the case and not vertically?

Comment: @EcTam If you define the unit normal vector as pointing outside the cube, then the face where $z = 0$ must have a unit normal vector of $(0, 0, -1)$. The face with a unit normal vector of $(0, 0, 1)$ is the face where $z = 3$. If you wanted to change the direction for a particular face, you would have to redefine the unit normal vector as pointing toward the inside. For a cylinder with a horizontal base, the unit normal on the curved surface points horizontally, and on its bases, it points vertically. I suggest you look at the images here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)